# How to add HTML tag to the last word of a string?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

How can add I HTML tags ( `<b> </b>` ) to the last word of a string?

The word is different for each result.

Language used : PHP
The string is a 1 line string ( the local market of city ) and inserted in a link

```
echo '<a href="'.$marche_permalink.'">'. $marche_title . '</a> ['. $hdebut .' - '. $hfin .']<br />';
```

The string is `$marche_title`.

Comment: That depends on the code you're using. Please edit your question and add it.

Comment: What defines the last word in the string? Any text after the last space in the string?

Comment: question edited to add requested infos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest interpretation of your question is this:

```
$formatted = preg_replace('/\S+$/', '<b>$0</b>', $string);
```

It will wrap any sequence of non-whitespace characters before the end of the string in the `<b>` tag. If there aren't any spaces, it will wrap the entire string in the tag, which should be okay because the entire string is the last word of the string.